# Get Background Image to Stop Tiling at Certain Point

Tags: html, css

I am trying to translate my PSD file to code and I am having problems with these headers. The header would contain the name of the header, and a horizontal purple bar that stretches from the right side of the end of the name to the end of the div. I am using [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) (responsive framework) and so I have given my header a width of three columns. I have written some code, but I am unsure how to get the purple line to not appear under the title name.

Currently, I have saved the purple line as a tileable image and set it as the background of the h3 tag. I have tried to play with the background position, but I cannot get the line from not appearing under the title name.

Here is a screenshot of part of the PSD file. To clarify, the purple bar next to `Hours`, `Phone`, and `Location` is not for the user to type any information onto; it is a decorative piece used to separate the different regions of information.

[image]

My code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns offset-by-one contact">
        <h3>Hours</h3>
    </div>
</div>

.contact h3 {
    color: #444;
    background: url(../img/purpleLine.jpg) bottom right repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Is the user supposed to enter anything in the space? If so how do you plan to do that?

Comment: The user is not suppose to enter anything in that space. Sorry, let me upload another screenshot to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a perfect time to use the HTML element `<span>` as this is pretty much exactly what it is meant to do.  After the  element, add `<span></span>`, give it the desired width you want, and set the background image for the span element. Not sure how your framework classes would be used to define the width, so I just put 'whatever' in that part.  You might even be able to assign a class to the span element to define its width.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns offset-by-one contact">
        <h3>Hours</h3><span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contact h3 {
    color: #444;
}
.contact span {
width:whatever;
background: url(../img/purpleLine.jpg) bottom right repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a div that has a bottom border of the purple colour and thickness you want. Then float it left and that would give you your desired affect. You can then also place a text box inside that div if need be.

Comment: How do you prevent div with the bottom border to not display the line under the text?

Comment: Add this CSS Property to the div text-decoration:none;

Comment: The purple line is still being displayed under the text. Can you show me the code that you would use please?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a live version of this page?

Comment: What you need to do is have 2 divs if you want the line to start after the text. <div1></div1><div2></div2>